# Работа с файловой системой

Tags: node.js

Всем привет) Прошу помочь разобраться в работе с файловой системой на ноде.
Искал инфу в официальной документации http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html , а так же на некоторых других сайтах. И появилось несколько вопросов.

В официальной доке есть такой метод для записи текста в файл `http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_encoding_callback`:

```
fs.writeFile(filename, data, [encoding], [callback]);
```

Этот метод прекрасно работает, но бродив по сети, я наткнулся на другой код(этот метод также есть в офф доке, но он там плохо прокомментирован):

```
fs.open("file.txt", "a", 0644, function(err, file_handle) {
if (!err) {
    fs.write(file_handle, 'текст', null, 'ascii', function(err, written) {
        if (!err) {
            // Всё прошло хорошо, делаем нужные действия и закрываем соединение с файлом.
            fs.close(file_handle);
        } else {
            // Произошла ошибка при записи
        }
    });
} else {
    // Обработка ошибок при открытии
}
});
```

Так в чём разница? На мой взгляд лучше использовать первый вариант, т.к. в нём совершается меньше операций, да и кода тоже меньше. Но так ли это?

1. Как перемещать файлы/папки?
2. Как определить размер файла?

Прошу не накидываться на меня, с файлами до этого ни разу не работал, по этому возможно, задаю глупые вопросы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***`fs.open`*** используется для открытия файлового дескриптора ( в доках, все функции в аргументах которой есть переменная ***`fd`*** - ожидают именно его, с т.з. JavaScript'a - файловый дескриптор это всего-навсего целое число ) и дальнейшей работы с ним, ***`fs.writeFile`*** - строго для записи в файл. Дескриптор вы можете открыть и не закрывать, т.е., получив ***`file_handle`*** ( он же ***fd*** ), можете легко и просто писать и читать.

Дабы было более понятно - представьте что ***`writeFile`*** - просто утилита, возможности которой заканчиваются на записи в файл, т.е. - мы не имеем никакого доступа ни к его статистике, не можем его просмотреть, удалить и т.д, все что мы умеем - писать в файл, к тому-же, после записи - утилита умирает ( т.е. мы имеем возможность строго единичной записи ). Во втором же случае, грубо говоря - мы открыли некий редактор и можем все - читать, смотреть инфу о файле, писать и т.д. ( это если грубо :) ). Только нельзя забывать "его" закрывать.

По поводу "лучше использовать первый вариант" - зависит от задачи. Если просто нужно "записать и забыть" - тогда да, лучше первый, если нет - лучше второй ( хотя опять таки зависит от задачи, с т.з. написанного кода - первый вариант все-равно короче и красивее, с другой стороны - код с использованием ***`fs.open`*** гибче )

Остальные вопросы:

1)

```
fs.rename(
    '/path/to/the/file/filename.ext',
    '/new/path/to/the/file/filename.ext',
    function( err ) { /*  */ }
)
```

2)

```
fs.stat( 'path/to/the/file/filename.ext', function( err, stat ) {
   if( !err ) {
      console.log( stat );      // -> file stats hash
      console.log( stat.size ); // -> file size 
   }
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за содержательные ответы!
Честно говоря, думал, что fs.rename() может только переименовывать)

Comment: Кстати, в получаемом файловом хэше есть кроме свойства size довольно много других свойств. Не мог бы ты пояснить что они значат, а то в документации я этого не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

> Как определить размер файла?

[Class: fs.Stats](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats)

> Как перемещать файлы/папки?

Для начала надо скопировать файл, а затем удалить начальный файл:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('util');

var is = fs.createReadStream('source_file')
var os = fs.createWriteStream('destination_file');

util.pump(is, os, function() {
    fs.unlinkSync('source_file');
});
```

Comment: Описанный вами способ перемещения файлов улыбнул... К тому-же - зачем тупо копипастить код с первых страниц выдачи гугла? :)